# Nested Functions - Processing

Tags: java, function, nested, processing, void

Can you build nested functions in Processing (Java?)
This code doesn't work. The compiler reads: unexpected token: void.

```
void keyPressed() {
         if(click1 = true) {
               graph();
         }
         if(click2= true) {
               points();
         }
         void graph() {
         ....
         ....
         }
 }
```

Comment: You can't do it in Java.

Comment: Anonymous class may be what you need.

Comment: Usually shouldn't do drawing in Processing's callBack functions. Use a flag there and call the drawing from `draw()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have nested functions. You can have anonymous classes, for example in a new thread:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // This is all in an anonymous Runnable class.
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this apply to Processing as well?

Comment: Oh this was a Java example. Processing doesn't have them either though.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said: no, you can't have "local functions" like that.

You also aren't doing your boolean comparison correctly, as a single = is assignment, not comparison. It should be either:

```
if(click1 == true) {
```

Or since you're already working with booleans, you can refer to it directly:

```
if(click1) {
```

Anyway, back to your question: you can't do what you're talking about, but you can get around it by using an anonymous class. To use an anonymous class, you need to have an existing class that you want to **extend** by overriding one or more of its functions, which you **can** do inside a method.

For example, we have the Runnable interface that we can implement by defining an anonymous class that defines the run() method, and then call that anonymous class directly. It looks like this:

```
void keyPressed() {
         if(click1) {
                  new Runnable(){
                           public void run(){
                                    //do graph stuff here
                           }
                  }.run();
         }
         if(click2) {
                  new Runnable(){
                           public void run(){
                                    //do points stuff here
                           }
                  }.run();
         }
 }
```

More info on anonymous inner classes here: http://staticvoidgames.com/tutorials/objects/advancedInheritance

However, all of this has a pretty bad code smell, and isn't the way any sane person would do this. Why do you think you need a local method? Chances are you should either use separate classes, or a regular old top-level method.